# Adding current logged on user to Managed By attribute of computer

Tags: powershell

I am in the process of learning `PowerShell` which impresses me more and more as days go by. My task is to automatically add the currently logged on user to `Managed By` attribute of computer object, where user is currently logged on, in `Active Directory`. For sure, this can be done with a `PowerShell` script, triggered via `GPO` as logon or logoff script. Obviously users have to be given right to read/write `Managed By` attribute of computer object in `AD`. I have found the `.vbs` script below but I want to use a `PowerShell` script.
How to solve this task?

```
Set objSysInfo = CreateObject(“ADSystemInfo”)
On Error Resume Next
Set objComputer = GetObject(“LDAP://” & objSysInfo.ComputerName)
objComputer.Put “managedBy”, objSysInfo.Username
objComputer.SetInfo
```

Answer (score 1):

The user will need rights to update this value in Active Directory.

```
Set-ADComputer $env:computername -ManagedBy (Get-ADUser $env:username)
```

**EDIT:**

This will run on the user's computer without any added components.

```
########################################################
# Get the current logged in user from Active Directory #
########################################################

$strName = $env:username

$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=User)(samAccountName=$strName))"
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

$objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne() 
$objUser = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()

$strLoggedInUser = $objUser.DistinguishedName 

########################################################
# Get the user's computer object from Active Directory #
########################################################

$strComputer = $env:computername

$strFilter = "(&(objectCategory=Computer)(cn=$strComputer))"
$objSearcher = New-Object System.DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher 
$objSearcher.Filter = $strFilter

$objPath = $objSearcher.FindOne() 
$objComputer = $objPath.GetDirectoryEntry()

###################################################
# Set ManagedBy attribute of the computer object. #
###################################################

$objComputer.ManagedBy = $strLoggedInUser
$objComputer.CommitChanges()
```

Place the following in a logon .bat file which will execute this script and bypass the execution policy.  Again, they will have to have permission to update this AD attribute, which I'm not sure what that permission will be.

```
PowerShell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command ".\SetComputerManagedBy.ps1"
```

Comment: Note that this requires the Active Directory module, first included in Windows Server 2008 R2 (load with `Import-Module ActiveDirectory`).

Comment: Hmmm, I have experience with logon scripts and GPO, but since PowerShell by default does not allow local execution of scripts. Also in this case used AD cmdlet does not exist on client computers, I have no idea how to solve this. If this means that on every computer I have to allow execution of scripts and importing of AD module then GPO with logon script is problematic. Shortly, I can not put Set-ADComputer $env:computername -ManagedBy (Get-ADUser $env:username) in script and trigger it via GPO when user logon.

Comment: Updated the script to not rely on the ActiveDirectory module or require the execution policy to be changed via GPO.